# EM Wave is totally transmitted at the boundary of two media. What does this mean about the polarisation of the incident wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, reflection

A plane EM waves travels from medium 1 to medium 2. For a particular angle of incidence the wave is totally transmitted. Apparently this means that the incident wave is polarised in the plane of reflection. I don't understand this. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe this is about Brewster's angle?

Comment: Ah yes. So since at Brewster's angle the intensity of the parallel polarised component of the electric field reflected falls to zero, this means that to satisfy the conditions the initial wave must be parallel polarised (otherwise there would still be a component reflected). @Pieter

Comment: @Pieter it'd be nice to see that expanded to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Brewster's angle there is no reflection of p-polarized light; all of it is transmitted (the red curves in the figure with the Fresnel coefficients).

[image: Power ratios air to glass, by "Kohlik17" on Wikimedia commons]